# Embed a Cognito Form into a Facebook fan page

Tags: facebook-pages, cognito-forms

How can a Cognito form be embedded or included into a Facebook fan page?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can use the Social media icons on the Publish page to post links to your forms. We do not currently have a Facebook app that would allow you to embed your form into a Facebook fan page.

This is something we are looking into but could be some time before its implemented. You can submit a [Feature Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest/) and we will be happy to keep you updated on the progress of this idea.